# eclipse does not Auto complete views for android.support.v4.? in xml file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, autocomplete, code-assist

Each time when I am trying to write layout xml file for ViewPager, I have to write it manually.

autocomplete works fine for TextView, EditView and all other views, however it does not work for ViewPager, or for PagerTitleStrip, and maybe for other views in support libraries.

the bellow screenshot shows that I don't have choices to autocomplete ViewPager.

[image]

I tried to add android-support-v4.jar to build path, but this is not work too, and I think it has no related with this issue.

[image]

so what is the problem with autocomplete for views in android.support.v4 ???
any suggestions ?